# Take the content of a message and repost discordjs

Tags: node.js

after a lot of trying here is my pb:

For example, I would like to say PV to my bot; /suggestion ABCDEFG

And that in a specific channel of my server it says: New suggestion \ n ABCDEFG

Comment: j'ai ce code ci : client.on('message', message => {
                                    if (message.content.startsWith('!test')) {
                                    var str = message.content
                                    message.channel.get(719634011042873365).send("Suggestion:" + str)
                                }
                                });

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution (replace CHANNEL ID by the id of the specific channel id):

```
client.on('message',message => {
   
    if(message.content.startsWith("/suggestion")) {
        var str = message.content.slice(11)
        client.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL ID").send("New suggestion \n"+str);
    }
```